# How to add outline for a GeometryInstance or PolygonGeometry in Cesiumjs

Tags: polygon, cesiumjs

I need to draw outline to the polygon primitive drawn with following code :

```
         scene.primitives.add( new Cesium.ClassificationPrimitive({
            geometryInstances : new Cesium.GeometryInstance({
                geometry : new Cesium.PolygonGeometry({
                    polygonHierarchy : new Cesium.PolygonHierarchy(
                        Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray(coords)
                    ),
                    height : height
                }),
                attributes : {
                    color: color,
                },
                id : id,
                description : "Highlight Object",
            })
        }));
```

Is there any way to draw outline to a polygon primitive? I am aware that it can be added with Entities but the requirement is to use primitives.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [PolylineCollection](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/PolylineCollection.html) as a separate primitive for outline.

I created a [demo in Sandcastle](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/#c=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) showing this use case:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

var coords = [
    -72.0, 40.0,
    -70.0, 35.0,
    -75.0, 30.0,
    -70.0, 30.0,
    -68.0, 40.0
];

var cartesian = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray(coords);

var color = Cesium.Color.DARKRED;
var outlineColor = Cesium.Color.GOLD;

var polygonPrimitive = new Cesium.Primitive({
    geometryInstances: new Cesium.GeometryInstance({
        id: 'polygon',
        geometry: Cesium.PolygonGeometry.createGeometry(
            new Cesium.PolygonGeometry({
                polygonHierarchy: new Cesium.PolygonHierarchy(cartesian)
            })
        )
    }),
    appearance: new Cesium.MaterialAppearance({
        material: new Cesium.Material.fromType('Color', {
            color: color
        })
    }),
    asynchronous: false
});

var polylinePrimitive = new Cesium.PolylineCollection();
polylinePrimitive.add({
    positions: cartesian,
    width: 3.0,
    loop: true,
    material: new Cesium.Material.fromType('Color', {
        color: outlineColor
    })
});

var primitives = viewer.scene.primitives;
primitives.add(polygonPrimitive);
primitives.add(polylinePrimitive);
```